# Селектор в переменную

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как id выбранного div поместить в переменную? Сейчас alert выдает [object Object].

```
$("#lastId").click(function() {
    $("div[id]:last").css("border", "1px solid red"); //подсвечивает div с last id
    var id = $("div[id]:last"); //переменная должна содержать название этого id
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var id = $('selector').attr('id');
```

Comment: работает, большое спасибо

Answer (score -1):

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

`this` — это обращение к вышестоящему элементу

Вроде бы только в функциях работает (лучше всего почитайте немного про `this`).